# Join two tables and group by id and last date SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables on sql server, which I have put together with a join. This causes the identifier of t1 to double.
And I would like to group by t1.id and get the last date in MySql I have managed to solve it, but in sql-server I can not find a solution

RESULT QUERY:

```
+-------+---------+------------+
| t1.id | t1.name |  t2.date   |
+-------+---------+------------+
|     1 | jhon    | 2019-04-03 |
|     1 | jhon    | 2019-04-01 |
|     2 | Beef    | NULL       |
|     3 | Peet    | NULL       |
+-------+---------+------------+
```

I WANT TO GET:

```
+-------+---------+------------+
| t1.id | t1.name |  t2.date   |
+-------+---------+------------+
|     1 | jhon    | 2019-04-03 |
|     2 | Beef    | NULL       |
|     3 | Peet    | NULL       |
+-------+---------+------------+
```

I try this:

```
Select * FROM (SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.date
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY t2.date desc) a
GROUP BY a.id,a.name, t2.date
```

Sql-server does not let me group without adding t2.date :(

Help me pls!

Comment: MAX(a.date) ... GROUP BY a.id,a.name

Answer (score 1):

You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, max(t2.date) t2date
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
group by  t1.id, t1.name
ORDER BY t2date desc
```

BTW, no need for a sub-query.

Comment: Mens. 8127, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 12
La columna "t2.date" de la cláusula ORDER BY no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.
Google Translate:
The "t2.date" column of the ORDER BY clause is not valid, because it is not contained in an aggregate function or in the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try below -

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, max(t2.date)
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY a.id,a.name
```

Comment: La columna 't2.date' de la lista de selección no es válida, porque no está contenida en una función de agregado ni en la cláusula GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * FROM 
(
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1.id), t1.name, t2.date
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY t2.date desc
) a
GROUP BY a.id,a.name, t2.date
```

Try This one....